# SQL group by fiscal/financial year

Tags: sql

Quick question, using the code below I just want to create a field displaying the records fiscal year and then group the results by the year.

The code to retrieve the results works however it does not want to group them by the fiscal year. I just get errors. I have tried multiple combinations using the forums but I can't get it to work. It is doing my head in!

This could be simple to resolve but I can't see it. Could anyone help?

Thanks!

```
Select m.jobno, m.premid, m.address,m.COMPDATE,

year(dateadd(month, -3, m.COMPDATE)) as FiscalYear


FROM miscvisit m

----- GROUP BY year(dateadd(month, -3, m.COMPDATE))
```

Comment: What kind of aggregation do you want to do in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query..

```
SELECT m.jobno
    ,m.premid
    ,m.address
    ,m.COMPDATE
    ,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, - 3, m.COMPDATE)) AS FiscalYear
FROM miscvisit m
GROUP BY m.jobno
    ,m.premid
    ,m.address
    ,m.COMPDATE
    ,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, - 3, m.COMPDATE))
```

Comment: Yikes ... why not just do `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select m.jobno, m.premid, m.address, 

year(dateadd(month, -3, m.COMPDATE)) as FiscalYear, sum([SalesField]) as Sales


FROM miscvisit m

GROUP BY 
m.jobno, m.premid, m.address, 
year(dateadd(month, -3, m.COMPDATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you seem to want to return the entire record, perhaps you really want an `ORDER BY` clause here:

```
SELECT
    jobno,
    premid,
    address,
    COMPDATE,
    YEAR(DATEADD(month, -3, COMPDATE)) AS FiscalYear
FROM miscvisit
GROUP BY
    YEAR(DATEADD(month, -3, COMPDATE))
ORDER BY
    FiscalYear;
```